Generalize for any $n,\;\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{n}}{(k-1)!}$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{n}}{(k-1)!}
$$
I came upon a puzzle problem which inspired me whether this sum could be generalised for any n. I asked all the math people I knew but they couldn't. I found for n=2,3,4... it can be evaluated. Also there is a strong and obvious reason to believe that it converges for any finite n. Can't generalize it. Can anyone of you here try?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$(k)^n$ is an integer polynomial of degree $n$ of $k-1,$ so it can be written as an integer  linear combination of terms of the falling factorials $(k)_m,$ for $m=0,\dots,n,$ and thus this sum can be written as an integer times $e.$

It's easy to show that it converges and give an expression in terms of the $n$th derivative of a function at $x=1$.  Would that satisfy you?

By the way, do you means $(k)^n$ as the rising factorial, or do you just mean $k^n.$ This doesn't affect my last comment - both are integer polynomials of degree $n.$

@ThomasAndrews  (k)^n is just k to the power n    And yes always the answer can be written as an integer multiplied by e, I found too!... Please try to make a generalised expression for any n integer.

Then don't put parentheses around for $k^n.$ The closed forms are messy.

You can spare a lot of people's time if you tell us, volunteering our time to help, what you know in your question, rather than after we spend time on it. @AbhibrataNandy

If by $(k)^n$ you mean just raising $k$ to the $n$-th power, then the reasult is
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(k)^{n}}{(k-1)!}=e B_{n+1},$
where $B$ are the Bell numbers .
This formula is known as Dobiński's formula.

But how? Proof? @Anixx

@AbhibrataNandy it is a known formula, known as Dobiński's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula

@AbhibrataNandy don't you mind upvoting and accepting the answer?

actually can't upvote my own answer as per now.. as i have less than 15 reputation... but obviously I will...

The <15 reputation problem should be solved.

@AbhibrataNandy you should not upvote your question, you should upvote my answer :-). Your question I have already upvoted.

@Anixx  upvoted man!

@Anixx please don't bully folks to get an accept?
